# Is it possible to play Cthulhu saves the world on Mac?

Tags: macos, cthulhu-saves-the-world

I recently bought Cthulhu saves the World on Steam, and was wondering if it was possible to play it by using Crossover, or other similar applications. It's also in the App store.

Answer (score 1):

I would try wine, which is essentially the basis of crossover. Cthulu Saves the World has a Gold Rating, but only for Gentoo Linux, which you can look up on the wine app database.
Unfortunately, running games on Steam through wine is fairly hit and miss, and there are several hoops to jump through. The first step is to install a windows version of Steam. Unfortunately, you may encounter a lack of text on Steam. Follow the instructions here: http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31374
Then, simply install as you would with any Mac game. If you have any issues, I would check the Wine appdb link above.
Good Luck!